# Should My Code Behind Calls my View Model or My Service Directly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am trying to use MVVM with my windows phone 7 app. I am kinda confused on how I should do this.

I have a codebehind event for Navigating in a web browser. Now this event will eventually call a method that will log the user in using Google oAuth.

Now the code to call the login method to Google is in my service layer. I am not sure if I should make a property in my VM that calls my service layer or if I should just directly make a service layer object in my codebehind page and call it directly.

What is the best way to go?

**Edit**

Here is what I did

// code behind

```
   private void wbGoogle_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            var queryParmas = e.Uri.ParseQueryString();

            var code = queryParmas.ToList().Where(x => x.Key == "code").FirstOrDefault();

            if (!code.Equals(new KeyValuePair<string, string>()))
            {
                loginVm.AuthenticateUser(code.Value, TestCallBack);
            }
        }

 private void TestCallBack(Authorization a)
        {
            var d = a;
            // maybe assign "a" to some property back in the VM.
        }
```

// Vm

```
public void AuthenticateUser(string code, Action<GoogleContacts.Model.Authorization> CallbackOnSuccess)
    {
        loginService.SendCode(code, CallbackOnSuccess);
    }
```

// service layer

```
  public void SendCode(string code, Action<Authorization> CallbackOnSuccess)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(TokenEndPoint, Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("code", code);
            request.AddParameter("client_id", ClientId);
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", SecretKey);
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", GrantType);
            request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", RedirectUrl);

            client.ExecuteAsync<Authorization>(request, response =>
            {
                CallbackOnSuccess(response.Data);
            });

        }
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in windows 7 apps, but if you have a view model, why do you have code behind? MVVM exists to avoid code behind, events are handled by your view model and as such your view model calls your service.

Comment: MVVM doesn't mean no code-behind. MVVM means that any code that isn't strictly related to the View only should be in the ViewModel.

Comment: Because the Web browser is a funny control and it is alot harder to do the binding and stuff and I don't think it is worth it.

Comment: You can use a toolkit such as MVVM Light. You can then let your View Model handle the logic and then just send navigation messages to your main view containiner your web browser

Comment: Looking at posted code: IMO, thumbs up. I think this is a good way to go. Perhaps though.. getting picky here... let the View Model get the response from the service and decide what to do on success or failuer.. on success it could then call your callback

Comment: @JoeB: MVVM is about putting as much as logic in the view model to that it can be tested. If it's too hard to handle events using MVVM only, you can still use event handlers in code behind but at least the logic that is executed should be in the view model. In the example there's too much logic in the code behind.

Comment: @tsiorn - can you give some example code? I was going to add a fail callback as well but was not sure where to put that one as well since it probably be a message box or something. I also what are thoughts about the TestCallBack method. Should it be assigning it's result to a property in the VM?

Comment: @tsiorn - Also wondering is it kinda weird that I have in my Code Behind a method that calls a method in my ViewModel that take 2 callbacks in that are actually in the codebehind to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View Model is a model of your view - it is where all your logical work is actually done. The responsibility of the View is to present information to the UI and collect user input. Any other tasks performed by the View begins to tightly couple your code-base, and you end up with a maintenance nightmare.

To answer your question directly, your View (Code-Behind) should pass the fact that a UI element has been clicked on to a method (command binding or other mechanism) in your View Model.

Then, you Veiw Model decides what to do next. It may decide that it's time to navigate to a particular web-page, at which time it signals the view to move to the requested page.

The precise method upon which the ViewModel and View communicate has a lot to do with which framework you are using, and if you are a "ViewModel First" or a "View First" kinda guy.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple... View Models are your business logic and brains of the app. The View should only deal with the display of data. I would consider authentication part of the "brains" and put that in your view model somewhere. You might even get a bit more sophisticated (depending on the needs of your app) and put the authentication Login method in a base class of your view model. This way the login call would be accessible via any page if need be.

Putting it in your code behind just tightly couples that code with your view - making it not very reusable. I would avoid that if you are going for the best architecture. Its ok to put stuff in your code behind of a view.

I would strongly disagree with the comment that MVVM exists to avoid code behind. The rule of thumb I use is this: Does the purpose of the View's codebehind exist to support view/display functions only? (perhaps you need to code to animate something or change a data template - thus changing its display). Code behind logic should be display specific. Thus, by this rule, a Login is not display specific and should not be a code behind method..

My 2 cents

Comment: So you would be against having the service layer be directly in my code behind and you are more for me calling my VM that calls the service layer and returns a result that gets set back in the Vm? I will post my code up and show what I have.

Comment: Yes, you got it. Keep it ouf of the view. Put it in a view model if that works or at the very least, add a static Authentication wrapper class or something... but your view model should make the call

Comment: A static wrapper? Try to avoid statics!